# Android gms vision on server side

Tags: android, google-play-services, vision

I want to use android gms vision library(to detect faces) from my server side.
I found that vision library wrapper use application context for work, so I can't use it outside android app.

Is there any way to build it for using outside app?
Maybe we can find a solution to build service with an emulator and use it for recognition?

This library has all things that i need, which i can not be achieved with opencv now

Answer (score 0):

This might help you for server side: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth

Comment: I don't understand how http auth can help me to build vision library for serverside?

Answer (score 0):

There is Google Cloud Vision API which is available not only for Android but  for Java, Python, NodeJS, iOS and Swift as well. You can see the different implementation in [Sample Applications page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/samples).

Comment: We need to build a standalone solution without using third party API. My question is about using vision library outside android app

Comment: Vision api is already 3rd party since it doesnt belong to you. What do you mean? Are you referring to google's vision api?

Comment: I do not put it right. I mean, that vision library from android sdk work without calling any http requests, so i looking the way to use it at my serverside. This library has all things that i need, which i can not be achieved with opencv now